# How many USB buses do Mac Pros have?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, usb

I know how many USB ports the Mac Pros have, but what I can't find is an answer to how many dedicated USB buses they have. Reason being, I'm involved in developing an app that uses 3 Kinects to track motion, and each Kinect will require a dedicated USB bus.

Will a stock Mac Pro have 3 separate buses, or will I need to add an extra USB controller card?

Comment: Related question but for Mac Mini: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55400/which-mac-mini-with-3-usb-controllers-can-be-recommended-for-high-bandwidth-usb Note that some busses are shared with other devices (port 2 is shared with the IR connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My new Mac Pro has 6 "USB" busses, 12Mb/s, and two "USB High Speed" busses. 480 Mb/s.  One of the "USB" busses shows Bluetooth on it, but none of the others seem to be in use.  The external connectors belong to the two "High Speed" busses.  Buss 0xfd has one of the front and two of the back connectors.  Buss 0xfa has one of the front and one of the back connectors.